# saving perdition model and insert new dataset into it

Tags: python, classification, data-science, prediction, knn

I have build a prediction model that shows how likely each customer get a credit card by using KNN model  as shown below

```
# Fitting KNN to the Training set:

classifier = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors = 7, metric = 'minkowski', p = 1,leaf_size = 1)
classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)

# Predicting the Test set results 
y_pred  = classifier.predict(X_test)

#Evaluate results
acc = accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred )
prec = precision_score(y_test, y_pred )
rec = recall_score(y_test, y_pred )
f1 = f1_score(y_test, y_pred )
f2 = fbeta_score(y_test, y_pred, beta=2.0)

results = pd.DataFrame([['K-Nearest Neighbours', acc, prec, rec, f1, f2]],
               columns = ['Model', 'Accuracy', 'Precision', 'Recall', 'F1 Score', 'F2 Score'])

print(results)
```

---

```
# Predict the Test set results

y_pred = best_model.predict(X_test)

#probability score
y_pred_probs = best_model.predict_proba(X_test)
y_pred_probs  = y_pred_probs [:, 1]
```

---

```
# Step 20: Format Final Results:

    final_results = pd.concat([ y_test], axis = 1).dropna()
    
    final_results['predictions'] = y_pred 
    
    final_results["propensity_to_pay(%)"] = y_pred_probs 
    
    final_results["propensity_to_pay(%)"] = final_results["propensity_to_pay(%)"]*100
    
    final_results["propensity_to_pay(%)"]=final_results["propensity_to_pay(%)"].round(2)
    
    final_results = final_results[[ 'Approved', 'predictions', 'propensity_to_pay(%)']]
    
    final_results ['Ranking'] = pd.qcut(final_results['propensity_to_pay(%)'].rank(method = 'first'),10,labels=range(10,0,-1))
    
    print (final_results)
```

the output is

```
        Approved  predictions  propensity_to_pay(%) Ranking
134         0            1                 57.14      10
212         0            0                 28.57      10
655         1            1                 85.71       2
83          1            1                 71.43       7
297         1            1                 71.43       7
..        ...          ...                   ...     ...
271         1            1                 71.43       2
517         0            1                 71.43       2
28          0            1                 57.14       7
377         1            1                 85.71       1
244         0            1                 71.43
```

i have saved the model using pickle as show below

```
# Save to file in the current working directory
pkl_filename = "pickle_modelKNN2332.pkl"
with open(pkl_filename, 'wb') as file:
    pickle.dump(classifier, file)

# Load from file
with open(pkl_filename, 'rb') as file:
    pickle_model = pickle.load(file)
```

how to insert new records into it to for example of i have a new cutsomer with theses data

```
 gender   YearsEmployed Income  Employed  CreditScore  Age   Debt    Married    Approved 

    b          1.25      30.83       t         6        30   4.460       y
```

how to get the value of Approved and the percentage of getting a credit card

Comment: Please provide as much information around your problem as you can to establish context. How is anybody supposed to know what this `pkl` serialized file is?
Refer https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for a guide template.

Comment: im trying to insert new data to the KNN model that is already been trained and tested. the aim here is to be able to predict whether or not  to give a new customer a credit card or not based on this model.

Answer (score 1):

```
import pickle 
  
# Save the trained model as a pickle string. 
saved_model = pickle.dumps(knn) 
  
# Load the pickled model 
knn_from_pickle = pickle.loads(saved_model) 
  
# Use the loaded pickled model to make predictions 
knn_from_pickle.predict(X_test)
```

reference => https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/saving-a-machine-learning-model/